# VBA to select row(s) containing same ID in column, highlight rows, then proceed to next ID and copy ID to clipboard

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I am looking for VBA code that will select row(s) containing the same ID in column A, highlight the rows, and then proceed to next unique ID in column A and copy the ID to my clipboard. This is to automate a very redundant process I have at work.

If it helps, here is a snippet of code from another macro that inserts a space between the unique ID's in column A:

```
 Dim lastRow As Long
 Dim x As Long
 lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 For x = lastRow To 2 Step -1
     If Cells(x, 1).Value <> Cells(x - 1, 1).Value Then
         If Cells(x, 1).Value <> "" Then
             If Cells(x - 1, 1).Value <> "" Then
                 Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
             End If
         End If
     End If

 Next x
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Use a filter here perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A filter wouldn't really work here. This is a macro I would run after all of the data has been formatted. I just need to automate the process of highlighting a row with matching IDs as a way to mark it off my list, move to the next ID, and copy it so I can do something with it in another program.

Comment: The filter was in regards to the copying ... I was proposing to filter with VBA. Are you copying one row or multiple rows?

Comment: I'd need to select entire row(s) with matching ID's in column A, highlight those green, and then select and copy the next unique ID in column A. I would run this macro over and over again using like ctrl + r.

Comment: So you can do this with a filter (with VBA); filter on the ID in column A; highlight visible rows green; proceed to next ID. That presumes you would run this in one step, not just over and over again.

Comment: How would I filter by a matching ID in column A? I'll need to run this macro over and over again. I basically just need this macro to automate me checking the rows off my list once I've worked them in another program. I've found out how to separate the unique ID's, I just can't figure out how to select the rows with unique ID's, highlight green, and proceed to next ID.

Comment: Ok I think I misunderstood what you're trying to do. In any case, if you have an empty row between each block of IDs, then you may be able to use `Range.End` to determine the start point of the next block.